# Execute function if the element was not selected before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, redactor

When the the div with `.redactor` class is clicked, check if it is already as the selected element.

- If it is already selected then do nothing.
- If it is newly selected then

  1. Execute the `initialize_redactor()` for that current selected div,
  2. And execute the `destroy_redactor()` if there was any div which was previously selected.
- And while any of the `.redactor` div is selected, if clicked other than the `.redactor` div, then execute `destroy_redactor()` for the currently selected `.redactor` div.

Sample in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Kakar/pen/wKvVLV)

html:

```
<div id="toolbar_wrapper">
  <div id="toolbar">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div class="redactor">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>

  <div class="redactor">
    <h1>Another Header</h1>
    <p>Another Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? Don't just give a set of requirements and a basic HTML structure...

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, you can check in the codepen link. I am confused on how to remove the old selected element and execute `destroy_redactor()` for that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through every ".redactor" element and run destroy_redactor on the selected element:

```
$('.redactor').on("click", function() {
    $(".redactor").each(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass("selected"))
        {
             destroy_redactor(current_edit);
             $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });

    $(this).addClass("selected");
    current_edit = $(this);
    initialize_redactor(current_edit);
});
```

Comment: Yes. Could you please also help me with the last problem please, if clicked other than the `.redactor` div execute the `destroy_redactor()` for current_edit.

Comment: Sure. Lines 2-8 of my code sample actually do this. Just run those lines whenever you need to clear the selected div. In fact, you don't need to keep track of current_edit, I just left it there because it was in your code and I didn't know if you were going to use it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add two more lines to your js

You will destroy ALL `.selected` AFTER you check if the redactor has a class of selected:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    destroy_redactor($('.selected'));
```

Then, if it already has the class selected, remove that class

```
} else {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Here's the codepen to try it out:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNEBNv

Comment: Yes. But it is executing even if it is already selected. I mean you click the same div more than once and it will initialize it more and more. How to stop that?